# center table in HTML

Tags: html, alignment, html-table

How can I center the `table` within a `div` using html?

I have placed my content within a `div` tag and set the `text-align` attribute to `center` like the following.

```
text-align: center;
```

This has not worked.

Below is my html.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <p>
    text test
            </p>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>300</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>400</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                    <td>600</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Give width to table, and set margin auto horizontally.

```
table {
  width:500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try the below

```
<table style="margin:0px auto; width:500px">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div style="text-align:center">    
   <table style="display: inline-table;">    
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the table tag like below

```
 <table border="1" align="center">
```

and  then check.

Comment: align tag is deprecated please use methods above @R.S

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
<p>
    text test
</p>
<table border="1" style="margin: 0 auto;">
<tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>600</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<div style="text-align:center">` you could write `<div style="width:600px;margin:0 auto">`
Which gives you a div with the width of 600 pixels and centers the div in the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0px auto` to your `table` tag

Answer (score 0):

you can put the style in the table

```
<table border="1" style="margin:0 auto;">
```

However I do suggest that you use a style sheet and not inline styles