# HTML/CSS center for all resolutions without % (percentage)

Tags: python, html, css, center

I was wondering, is it possible to make this central box be "in the very" center of the page without using %?

I'm using VPS and I have some Python going on there, so I don't know how to use % sizes in order to get it right. But this is how far I came up only to hear that this isn't centered on 1280x1024:

https://s18.postimg.org/vta0qfd5l/2809583a0f43627d0fc1b428863b3faa.jpg

This is the code I have used:

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #121212;
  background-image: url("https://app.box.com/shared/static/vgfs65li424fk8h4n5e23pm7070yrewq.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-height: auto;
  max width: 1200px;
}
table {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 265px;
  border: 5px ridge yellow;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
div {
  text-align: center;
  align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>

  </table>
</div>
```

So, any idea what I can improve to "nail it"? I've noticed that if I add more to max-width complete box moves to the left. Maybe if I can solve this, I would solve the first problem as well?

This question is unique because I can't use percentage in order to align table properly, so I just want to know if this is possible at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Wich box are you talking about?

Comment: Provide fiddle or codepen to better understand.!

Comment: how far back in IE versions you have to go?

Comment: IE is not important at all.

@Bálint box in the center with the registration form

Comment: It looks fairly centred to me, what am I missing?

Comment: 1280x1024 resolution gets "wrong"

https://s18.postimg.org/vta0qfd5l/2809583a0f43627d0fc1b428863b3faa.jpg

So, I just want to know if it's possible at all to center 100% without using percentage. I mean, it's not a big deal, but, lets say I'm curious to learn something about this issue and move on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [center table in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469383/center-table-in-html)

Comment: Is % safe to use for just the height of the window?

Comment: I don't know how to use it, tried %% and %' but didn't help at all.

When I put % I get this error: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: unsupported format character '"' (0x22) - I've googled it and it says it's related to Python. I can try, just let me know what I need to input?

Answer (score 1):

If your page is served as a HTML webpage, you *should* be able to use JS, HTML, and CSS without your backend mucking it up. If you apply the following styles to **any** element, it will be centered:

```
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

There were some errors as well which would pretty much frag the remaining styles you might've expected:

```
background-height
```

Does not exist.

```
min width:
```

should be:

```
> min-width:
```

and

```
align: center;
```

doesn't exist either.

In this Snippet I corrected the previously mentioned errors and refactored a substantial amount. You have a div framing the table, so it made more sense to center the div and make sure that the table stays within the div. Let me know if I'm close to expected results or not.

#### SNIPPET 1

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #121212;
  background-image: url("https://app.box.com/shared/static/vgfs65li424fk8h4n5e23pm7070yrewq.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 265px;
  border: 5px ridge yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>

  </table>
</div>
```

This solution should work, but if you insist on not using percentages for reasons beyond my comprehension, then consider the viewport measurement unit.

```
100vw = 100% of viewport width
100vh = 100% of viewport height
```

The big difference between percentage unit of measure and viewport unit of measure is that percentage lengths are determined by whatever contains the subject element being measured. While a viewport length is determined by the dimensions of your viewable area of the screen. See the following Snippet to see the difference, view it in full page mode and resize to test the demonstration at different dimensions. For more on `vw` and `vh` refer to this [article](http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design).

#### SNIPPET 2

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
#A {
  border: 3px dotted red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
}
#B {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .4);
}
#C {
  border: 2px dashed yellow;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 255, .4);
}
```

```html
<p>Viewable area of browser is viewport. View this in Full page mode and resize the browser at various sizes. Div B (blue) doesn't change. Div C (yellow) does.</p>


<div id='A'>
  A width: 500px height: 250px
  <div id='B'>B width: 50% height: 50%</div>
  <div id='C'>C width: 50vw height: 50vh</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your very constructive post and I will definitely have something nice to learn something out from it, but - #1 - I use Python for running the server - so, using % breaks the page and makes it unusable and I haven't found a way how to use % for sizing. #2 I used max-width, not "min width" #3 I used align: center as seen div use that, so I probably did a mistake when I transfered that to table. Checked now and the code acts the same with or without align - thanks for noting that out.

Comment: And just to honor you as you paid attention to my problem - the reason I don't use % is because I get this type of error then: http://image.prntscr.com/image/60b5ec26994b4dbe9aba656fc3648d28.png

I just put width: 20%; and got this as a result. I've googled it out before opening this question and there is a definitelly problem between Python and **%** symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can position it using absolute positions in CSS and measurements in px.  If you are using Jquery then you can get the document sizes using

```
$(document).height();
$(document).width();
```

or 
   $(window).height(); // for the viewport.

Some quick JavaScript calculations should allow you to dynamically position something anywhere you want.
Don't forget to bind .resize() events to adapt to user adjusting browser size.
Heres a nice article on getting window sizes etc.

https://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewportwindow-size-width-and-height-javascript

Comment: I'm using VPS (Linux, Debian 7) at the moment, so I'm not quite sure if I can upload any additional content - for example I know that I had to put background image externally in order to get it loaded, so I would like to see if there's anything else I can do with CSS?

Or maybe, better question - as I'm using Python for this server, is there a way to use top: 50%; left: 50%? I've tried with %% and with %' but nothing occured, maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help, but I talked to a friend meanwhile and we came up to satisfying solution, so here's the final code and what we did

1. I removed the table from the body and other non-necessary items (forgive me, as I'm a newbie)
2. Instead of max height and width we used height and width - we had to fine tune height so that all browsers can display content properly and I have tested this out on cellphone, iPad, several monitors, everything is shown in a way I would like to.
3. Except for IE8... but honestly, it doesn't matter :)

```css
<style>h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #121212;
  background-image: url("https://app.box.com/shared/static/vgfs65li424fk8h4n5e23pm7070yrewq.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
.FormBody {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 380px;
  height: 305px;
  border: 5px ridge gold;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>CTLServer REGISTRACIJA</title>
</head>
<script src="/md5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  function makeHash() {
    a = document.getElementById('serial').value;
    a = a.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '').replace(/-/g, '').toUpperCase();
    if (!a.match(/^[A-Z0-9]{20}$/)) {
      alert('Neispravan serijski broj.');
      return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('serial').value = a;
    while (a.length < 36) {
      a += '\0';
    }
    u = document.getElementById('username').value;
    u = u.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
    if (u.length < 3 || !u.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
      alert('Zabranjeno ime za korisnika - dozvoljeno 3-36 alfa-numerička znaka (0-9 | a-z | A-Z).');
      return false;
    }
    p = document.getElementById('password').value;
    if (p.length < 3) {
      alert('Lozinka je kratka - minimum 3 alfa-numerička znaka (0-9 | a-z | A-Z)');
      return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('hash').value = hex_md5(a + u + '-' + p);
    return true;
  }
</script>
<div class="FormBody">
  <br />
  <h2><u>• CTLServer REGISTRACIJA •</h2>
  </u>
  <strong><a href="https://app.box.com/shared/static/krtchlikkjw48u21aywx">LINK za HOST</a><br /></strong>
  <br />
  <form name="registration" action="/register" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="nonce" id="nonce" value="%(nonce)s" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash" size="32" value="" />
    <strong>Serijski Broj:</strong>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="serial" id="serial" size="40" value="%(serial)s" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('btnGen').click(); return false;}" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Korisničko Ime:</strong>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="user" id="username" size="40" value="%(username)s" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('btnGen').click(); return false;}" />
    <br />
  </form>
  <strong>Lozinka:</strong>
  <br />
  <input type="password" id="password" size="40" value="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('btnGen').click(); return false;}" />
  <br />
  <p>
    <input class="button" type="button" id="btnGen" value="Registruj se" onclick="if (makeHash()) {document.forms['registration'].submit();}" />
  </p>
</div>

</html>
```

So once again, thanks for all your help, especially @zer00ne I will definitely read your post briefly couple of times as I think there is a lot I can understand from there. And as a matter of fact I think I'm gonna try other methods as well, just to make it work in case I'm gonna need them at some point.

Comment: Do you know what library you have for HTML parsing? Is it ElementTree, Beautiful Soup, lxml, twisted, etc.? I'm not a Python programmer, but as far as I recall you either use regular expression or a library to parse HTML if you are serving it from Python. The pic you posted shows an error message because of  a semi-colon `;`, so if it was a `%` before, it looks as if a semi-colon `;` now. If you insist doing it old school with regular expression, try escaping symbols that Python is rejecting. In general what you do is place a `\` in front of the offending symbol.

Comment: I have added a Python tag to your post, you'll get better results. BTW, I wholeheartedly agree, IE8 is not a concern.

Comment: I think it's twisted. I've seen it during installing the server. So just to recap if I want Python to override % symbol I need to put it in this format width: 50'% ?

Comment: Try this [article](https://www.junian.net/2014/07/simple-http-server-and-client-in-python.html) it instruct you to make a server and client. In RegEx, if you wanted to use `width: 50%` then try `width: 50\%` that's called escaping. By putting a backslash before an entity, you are designating that particular symbol/entity/character as it's literal (e.g. in a url hash a space key is this `%20` if you escape the percentage symbol like this: \%20, the interpreter will see `%20` instead of a spacebar keystroke.)