# Why wont my table center?

Tags: html, css, html-table, footer

I can't figure out why my table of images won't stay inside of the content part of my page. Also wondering why my footer won't stay at the bottom of the page. My page needs to look like this image:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/QIKAj]

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.mainwrapper {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pagebanner {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0;
}

.pagebanner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: brown;
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.headersd {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

.subheading {
  background-color: #f8d631;
  text-align: center;
}

.subheading h2 {
  background-color: #f8d631;
  margin: 0;
}

.table {
  align: center;
  padding-left: 50px border: 20px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainwrapper">
  <div class="pagebanner">
    <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1400/1*278tqw9zNPe2WCAz29Wzdw.jpeg" alt="PageBanner">
  </div>
  <!--PageBanner-->

  <div class="main">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Information</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Navbar-->

    <div class="headers">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>The Club Site</h1>
      </div>
      <!--Main page heading section-->

      <div class="subheading">
        <h2>Members Prices</h2>
      </div>
      <!--Sub heading section-->
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <table>
        <th>Discount Prices</th>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://imgur.com/S1JVX6K" </td>
            <td><img src="https://imgur.com/uzkB81W" </td>
              <td><img src="https://imgur.com/YvnOW4s" </td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://imgur.com/f2wnDXT" </td>
            <td><img src="https://imgur.com/XiBYnS2" </td>
              <td><img src="https://imgur.com/mGcCorr" </td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Table Section-->

  </div>
  <!--Content section-->

  <div class="footer">
    <footer>wsrgferg</footer>
  </div>
  <!--Footer section-->
</div>
<!--Endwrapper-->
```

Comment: Please provide the absolute path to all the images. What I currently see is [this](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/qxEbNP).

Comment: I'll guess for the footer problem,I think it is because your whole content haven't reached the bottom part of the browser, so there this some space left. Try adding some more elements, and see what happens

Comment: Ah sorry about that, should be fixed now. As for the footer is it possible to fix it to the bottom of the navbar section?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [center table in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469383/center-table-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0 auto` in **table** tag and change **th** to **h3** and make **h3** `text-align:center`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bazaar Ceramics</title>

<style>

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.mainwrapper {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.pagebanner {
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0;
}

.pagebanner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: brown;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.headersd {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 500px;
}

.header {
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}

.subheading {
    background-color: #f8d631;
    text-align: center;
}

.subheading h2 {
    background-color: #f8d631;
    margin: 0;
}

.table {
    align: center;
    padding-left:50px
    border: 20px;
    }
.footer {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    height:20px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}   
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="mainwrapper">
        <div class="pagebanner">
          <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1400/1*278tqw9zNPe2WCAz29Wzdw.jpeg" alt="PageBanner">
        </div><!--PageBanner-->

    <div class="main">
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Information</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--Navbar-->

    <div class="headers">
    <div class="header">
            <h1>The Club Site</h1>
    </div><!--Main page heading section-->

    <div class="subheading">
            <h2>Members Prices</h2>
    </div><!--Sub heading section-->
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="table"> 
            <table style="margin:0 auto;" >
            <h3 style="text-align:center;">Discount Prices</h3>
            <tr><td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot002_smaller.jpg"</td><td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot006_smaller.jpg"</td><td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot013_smaller.jpg"</td></tr>
            <tr><td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot002_smaller.jpg"</td><td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot006_smaller.jpg"</td><td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot013_smaller.jpg"</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div><!--Table Section-->  

    </div><!--Content section-->

    <div class="footer">
        <footer>wsrgferg</footer>
    </div><!--Footer section-->
    </div><!--Endwrapper-->

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: The header worked but changing the margin 0 auto to the table styling didn't change anything.

Comment: replace your table tag(<table>) with <table style="margin: 0 auto">

Comment: I did, had no effect.

Comment: Then you need to put you code in running environment like jsfiddle

Comment: Ahk they said I should be able to do it purely with html and css. It should be possible right?

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.mainwrapper {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pagebanner {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0;
}

.pagebanner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: brown;
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.headersd {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

.subheading {
  background-color: #f8d631;
  text-align: center;
}

.subheading h2 {
  background-color: #f8d631;
  margin: 0;
}

.table {
  align: center;
  padding-left: 50px border: 20px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.content {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Bazaar Ceramics</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="mainwrapper">
    <div class="pagebanner">
      <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1400/1*278tqw9zNPe2WCAz29Wzdw.jpeg" alt="PageBanner">
    </div>
    <!--PageBanner-->

    <div class="main">
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Information</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--Navbar-->

      <div class="headers">
        <div class="header">
          <h1>The Club Site</h1>
        </div>
        <!--Main page heading section-->

        <div class="subheading">
          <h2>Members Prices</h2>
        </div>
        <!--Sub heading section-->
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="table">
        <table style="margin:0 auto;">
          <h3 style="text-align:center;">Discount Prices</h3>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot002_smaller.jpg" </td>
              <td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot006_smaller.jpg" </td>
                <td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot013_smaller.jpg" </td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot002_smaller.jpg" </td>
              <td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot006_smaller.jpg" </td>
                <td><img src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot013_smaller.jpg" </td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!--Table Section-->

    </div>
    <!--Content section-->

    <div class="footer">
      <footer>This is the Footer</footer>
    </div>
    <!--Footer section-->
  </div>
  <!--Endwrapper-->

</body>



</html>
```

If you add to your `.content` a `min-height` of an absolute height (like pixel) then your content will always use this place and your footer will be right under the fix hight you gave your content.

The Problem is that your content is only using about 20% of the screen and right under this 20% your footer will be attached to this. If you add more Content to your page then the footer will be pressed down because your page then maybe need 80% of the height of the screen.

This is not the best soulution because it's not really responsive but it works. Better soulutions are welcome.

Comment: You are required to post your code here within your answer, not a third party site. Links go dead and your answer will help no one in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob thank you for commenting i will notice this for future anwsers